# Display a system message in a chatroom

Tags: swift, xcode, chat, messagekit

I am struggling on how to display a system message in a chatroom. Currently, I have already built the chatroom using MessageKit in Swift and finished the overall UI. What I want is, when I click the red button at the upper right corner, a system message "The button is tapped" will automatically display in the chatroom, like the sample picture below. Thanks a lot if anyone can help!

[sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbDqT.png)

Answer (score 0):

This answer may be a bit late but the solution is quite simple. All you need to do is create a custom cell and configure it with the messages view controller data source.

There's a [comprehensive guide](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/master/Documentation/CUSTOM_CELLS.md) you can follow on the official repo for help with what to do alongside an [example](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit/blob/05b481c1f7eda0233d1a8eaaec5fd0aa9b75a142/Example/Sources/Views/CustomCell.swift)

Here's some demo code (you won't be able to copy and paste this since I'm referencing some custom UIView subclasses)

Firstly, create your `UICollectionViewCell`

```swift
class SystemMessageCell: CollectionCell<MessageType> {
  lazy var messageText = Label()
    .variant(.regular(.small))
    .color(.gray)
    .align(.center)

  override func setupView() {
    addSubview(messageText)
  }

  override func setupConstraints() {
    messageText.snp.makeConstraints { $0.edges.equalToSuperview() }
  }

  override func update() {
    guard let item = item else { return }
    switch item.kind {
    case .custom(let kind):
      guard let kind = kind as? ChatMessageViewModel.Kind else { return }
      switch kind {
      case .system(let systemMessage):
        messageText.text = systemMessage
      }
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}
```

Secondly, you need to create two separate files.
One is a size calculator and the other is a custom flow layout.

```swift
class SystemMessageSizeCalculator: MessageSizeCalculator {
  override func messageContainerSize(for message: MessageType) -> CGSize {
    // Just return a fixed height.
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 20)
  }
}
```

```swift
class SystemMessageFlowLayout: MessagesCollectionViewFlowLayout {
  lazy open var sizeCalculator = SystemMessageSizeCalculator(layout: self)

  override open func cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> CellSizeCalculator {
    let message = messagesDataSource.messageForItem(at: indexPath, in: messagesCollectionView)
    if case .custom = message.kind {
      return sizeCalculator
    }
    return super.cellSizeCalculatorForItem(at: indexPath);
  }
}
```

Finally, hook it all up in your MessagesViewController like so:

```swift
class ChatViewController: MessagesViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    messagesCollectionView = MessagesCollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: SystemMessageFlowLayout())
    super.viewDidLoad()
    messagesCollectionView.register(SystemMessageCell.self)
  }

  // MARK: - Custom Cell

  override open func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let messagesDataSource = messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource else {
      fatalError("Ouch. nil data source for messages")
    }

    let message = messagesDataSource.messageForItem(at: indexPath, in: messagesCollectionView)
    if case .custom = message.kind {
      let cell = messagesCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(SystemMessageCell.self, for: indexPath)
      cell.item = message
      return cell
    }
    return super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath)
  }
}
```

The end result will be something like this:

[image: Sample screenshot]

Comment: I have a question ???. I want to add an attribute string to .custom(). It's ok ????